# Python: Catch output of console in antoher console

Tags: python, console, stdout

Let's say I have **myscript.py**:

```
while True:
    print("hi")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now launching it in *mainscript.py*  as subprocess:

```
sub = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-u", myscript.py], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
```

Now I read the output of myscript.py:

```
while sub.poll() == None:
    subm = sub.stdout.readline()
    print (subm)      #print for checking only
```

But this only works, when I don't create a new console. But I need this console window.

How can I catch/access the output of another console window?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.
Is this what you are searching for?

```
import sys, subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "-u", os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/myscript.py'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, bufsize=1)

if p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line,
p.wait()
```